# help with equivalence relations

Tags: equivalence-relations

I am having trouble understanding the concepts of reflexivity, symmetric, and transitivity
For the set of all real numbers, are the following two statements an equivalence relation:

x + y is an integer and

x-y is an irrational number

and whether x<=y and x + y = 0 are circular

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by circular?

Comment: I know that x + y = 0 is not transative, but am having trouble setting up if x<= y is

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solved example for $x+y$ is an integer. Try to do the others along the same lines. Recall that then $x \sim y$ iff $x+y$ is an integer, $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ (which is assumed).

(1) $x \sim x$ (reflexive): If $x \in \mathbb{R}$, then, usually, $x+x = 2x \notin \mathbb{Z}$. Example, $x = \frac{1}{3}$. As one counterexample is enough, it is not reflexive.

(2) $x \sim y \Rightarrow y \sim x$ (symmetric): If $x + y \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $y + x = x+y \in \mathbb{Z}$ as the reals commute, so it is symmetric

(3) $x \sim y, y \sim z \Rightarrow x \sim z$ (transitive): You are given
$$x + y \in \mathbb{Z}, y + z \in \mathbb{Z}, \quad (1)$$
and want to conclude
$$ x+z \in \mathbb{Z}. \quad (2)$$
Now this must hold for all reals that satisfy (1). So let 
$$x = \frac{1}{3} = z, y = \frac{2}{3},$$
which is easily seen to satisfy (1). But obviously $x+z = \frac{2}{3} \notin \mathbb{Z},$ so (2) is not satisfied. So you have found one example in which the relation would not be transitive, so it is not transitive, and so this is not an ER.

*Edit*: as to your comment whether $x \leq y$ is transitive, it is (by well-ordering), but you should try to show this yourself to get some exercise.

Comment: I understood "For the set of real numbers" in the question to mean that we want to know whether "$x+y$ is an integer" defines an equivalence relation *on the set of real numbers*.  With this meaning, reflexivity fails, since there are real numbers $x$ for which $x+x$ is not an integer.

Comment: @AndreasBlass: Good point, and shamed ducking. I will adjust the solution. Thanks for your vigilance.